# Xcode 11 live preview on device fails, but app runs correctly

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to preview my views on a real device, but Xcode fails when I click the button:

[image: Cannot preview in this file – unexpected error occurred]

Clicking the "Diagnostics" button shows the following error:

```
UVIntegration.ConcreteHardwareDevice.(unknown context at $13f0b5314).(unknown context at $13f0b531c).InstallError.failedToInstall(Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402620394 "Unable to install "AppName"" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to install "AppName", NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe0360a1c50 {Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402620394 "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)., com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(

----------------------------------------

GenericHumanReadableError: unexpected error occurred

failedToInstall(Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402620394 "Unable to install "AppName"" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to install "AppName", NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe0360a1c50 {Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=-402620394 "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)., com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001217c66e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001217c6de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012180656a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 164
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106e95c12 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000121806301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
    5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000012168ea25 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106fc6e7a __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106fc8552 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72809583 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7280a50e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7280face _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72810452 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72819a9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff72a6371b _pthread_wqthread + 290
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff72a6357b start_wqthread + 15
), DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, NSLocalizedDescription=The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.}}})
```

The above suggests that my provisioning setup is wrong, but if I click the "run" button, the app is deployed and runs absolutely fine on my devices.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance you share your code so I try on my machine ?

Comment: @ShaherKassam sadly I can't share the whole project as it's owner by my employer.

Comment: This is Xcode Bug. mostly it resolved by clear cache and restart xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working!

Whilst everything with the app bundle was correct (which is why the app ran on-device absolutely fine), the Tests and UITests bundles had the wrong team selected for their signing, and after I changed those I got errors saying that the bundle ID for my test bundle couldn't be registered to our team. I changed my bundle IDs and now I can preview my app on-device!

Answer (score 1):

Following fixed for me:

Select your command line tool by going to: `Preferences > location > commandLine tools [drop down] > select Xcode 11` It be selected to previous one (i.e Xcode 10)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my settings there are correct.

Comment: Ok, what about the console error: `UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)`

Answer (score 0):

I had issues in Xcode 11, updating to latest version solved my problem